# How to make iOS app that will work from iOS 4.3 on Xcode 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to make iOS(iPad and iPhone) app that will work from iOS 4.3 version on Xcode 5.0.

Lets call my project TESTING.

Here is what I have done:

1. PROJECT TESTING, Info, iOS Deployment Target set 4.3
2. Removed Storyboard -> because they are supported from iOS 5.0 version
3. Removed Auto Layout -> because it is supported from iOS 6.0 version
4. I have added in TESTING-Info.plist "Main nib file base name" correctly for Window, View or Application.
5. Added XIB file, and this is where the problem starts

What should I add: Window, View or Application ?

I have tried all and these are the results:

View -> will not show View ( I added some controls, like: text field, label)

Application and Window are working fine in simulator.

BUT on iPhone (iOS 6.x) text field is not working, keyboard is shown bit it will not accept input.

How to do it correctly ?

Comment: ios 4 and 5 is practically dead. Don't bother supporting under 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the *File's Owner* to `UIApplication`.
2. Add `NSObject` and set its class to your App Delegate.
3. Connect `UIApplication.delegate` with the App Delegate object.
4. Add `UIWindow` and **make sure *Visible at Launch* is checked on**. This may cause wrong text input behavior.
5. Connect the window with App Delegate `window` property.

---

**Edit 1**: I don't understand why people bother with this XIB. Here is the code equivalent:

- In `main.m`:

  ```
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"YourAppDelegate"));
  ```
- In `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

  ```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  ```

---

**Edit 2**: *Neal* is right about supporting older iOS versions. Why you need to support iOS 4.3, my god?!

Comment: What should I add: Window, View or Application ? -> I did not get that part.

Comment: If you are talking about template names, because you didn't mention what the hell are the _Window, View or Application_ you refer to, choose Empty. They are all basically the same.

Comment: @WebOrCode If you already have the XIB running on simulator, just having the problem with keboard input on iOS 6, see the text highlighted in bold. Everything else is just for completeness.

Comment: Window, View or Application is what you get when do File -> -> New -> File... select iOS (User Interface), you can pick: Storyboard, View, Empty, Window or Application.

Comment: It look like whole was in this "make sure Visible at Launch is checked on". But I had problem with CTRL + Drag to my TestingViewController.h. Way how I solved it was following. I made View Controller in XIB, Window rootViewController is connected to new View Controller, and Class of ViewController is TestingViewController. Is there easier way ?

Answer (score 2):

With the state of iOS currently, Apple suggests it is not necessary for new apps to support anything but iOS 7. That seems a bit unrealistic, but I would suggest you don't need to support anything prior to iOS 6. Supporting prior to iOS 5 would be extremely problematic for any non-trivial app.

While this doesn't seem to be your issue at the moment, there's a big issue supporting iOS <5: ARC. ARC `strong` references are a compiler feature and can be easily be compiled for iOS 4, but ARC `weak` references require OS support and cooperation. You can work around this using `__unsafe_unretain` or `assign` where you might otherwise use weak references. There are some limitations to this, but it works generally.

Also of note, I've encountered a bug with `UITextField` that applies on iOS 6.x when compiled with the iOS 7 SDK. The bug is if the field has no text, `textField.text` returns `nil` instead of `@""`. This isn't a big issue, but if you do something like `textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];` the value will never grow because `[nil anything]` always returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Near 95% devices use iOS 6 or iOS 7. It would be easier develop for 95% devices with Xcode 5 rather than begin at iOS 4.3.

Comment: Where can I see those statistics ?

Comment: Is there anything official from Apple ? Like http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html for Android ?

Comment: Not sure. I think that Apple only share this info through dev portal.

Comment: Apple doesn't share stats, but all 3rd party stats will tell you one thing: _iOS 5 is dead_. Not to mention iOS 4.